# Node Template build errors

Tags: rust-cargo, substrate

Followed steps from this link https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/setup

but getting errors after >cargo build --release

error[E0277]: the trait bound `<System as Trait>::BlockNumber: From<i32>` is not satisfied
--> /Users/ion/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/frame-executive-2.0.0/src/lib.rs:471:37
|
471 |             header.number().saturating_sub(1.into())
|                                              ^^^^ the trait `From<i32>` is not implemented for `<System as Trait>::BlockNumber`
|
= note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<<System as Trait>::BlockNumber>` for `i32`
help: consider further restricting the associated type
|
449 |     pub fn offchain_worker(header: &System::Header) where ::BlockNumber: From {

Actually, there were 2 other couple errors, but I managed to get past those. Any tips on how to resolve this?

Comment: There is a bug in the current Rust nightly. Can you please try running these steps and trying again? https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/issues/90#issuecomment-706041447

Comment: Thanks! Now managed to compile SNT w/o any error.